# DataTables update buttons after loading new data

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using datatables for my table and main reason why I wanted to use it was to make downloading/saving the data easy. The problem is my table is empty at first and the data gets loaded depending on the user query. the problem is the buttons don't seem to update. For example I see data in my table after a query but clicking on print gives me a print page with only the table headers and no data.

How do I update the data for the buttons. I have tried destroying the table and reinitializing it but the results are the same. I even tried removing the whole table DOM object and creating it again with js and then reinitializing the DataTable but the same results.

Here's how I tried destroying and reinitializing the DataTable:

```
$('#numberTable').DataTable().destroy(); 
$('#numberTable').DataTable( {
     dom: 'Bfrtip',
     buttons: [
         'print', 'excel', 'pdf'
     ]
});
```

How do I reload the table and/or the buttons so they work after populating my table with data?

**SOLUTION:**
Adding data should be done using [Add rows](https://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buttons do need the Buttons-Extensions to work correctly. Did you integrate that extension correctly?
[Get DataTables with extensions](https://datatables.net/download/index)

Comment: The buttons appear correctly and when I put some data in the table those rows show up in print, excel etc but the data that doesn't show up is the data I add in the table later on using a function. So that makes me think I need to refresh/reload the whole table.

Comment: May I ask how you inserted the data?

Comment: I just append it using jquery. like this: `$("#numberTable tbody").append("<tr><td>"+number+"</td><td>"+data[0]+"</td><td>"+data[1]+"</td></tr>");`

Comment: ok, that doesn't affect the internal datastorage, you should use [Add rows](https://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html) instead.